# Вертикальная камера в Unity

Tags: unity3d, камера, unity3d-android

как сделать запрет на горизонтальную камеру в Unity? Если включить авто-поворот на телефоне то игра становиться багнутой при горизонтальном положении телефона.В юнити на камере настройки = 9:16 Portrait(16:9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build Setting -> Player Setting -> Resolution And Presentation -> Default Orentation -> Portrait

Answer (score 0):

File ->  Build Setting ->  Выберите андроид и применить, дальше во вкладке, где расширения, появится то, что нужно.